# How to print string location and how to replace string but skip some string apply C language to Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Example:"I have a pen.I have a pineapple. Uh..pineapplepen. pen pineapple apple pen."

Q1:Please print out the position of the word pen in the example sentence. **apply C language to Arduino.**

Q2:In the example sentence, all the words "pen" are changed to "apple"
[Note]: The pen of **pineapplepen is not included.** Please explain the code. **apply C language to Arduino.**

My friend do it by **C#**, but I don't know how to do that **apply C language to Arduino.**

```
//by C#
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
   var source = "I have a pen.I have a pineapple. Uh..pineapplepen. pen pineapple apple pen.";
        String target= "pen";
        Regex regex= new Regex("(^|[\\s.,])("+ target + ")(?=[\\s.,])");
        foreach(Match match in regex.Matches(source)) {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Index+match.Groups[1].Length);
        }

        var result= regex.Replace(source,x=>x.Groups[1]+"apple");
            
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
   }
 }
```

Comment: C doesn't have support for regular expressions without additional libraries, so your friends example won't help you. You need to manually search for words in the string.

Comment: Running regex on an Arduino is pretty much like playing fetch with your tame elephant inside a doll house-sized porcelain store.

Comment: Also (un)fortunately Arduino isn't using C but C++. So you can use C++ strings or the Arduino bastard version of them. Either is a horrible idea on a 8 bit MCU, but it's at least easier to program than manual string handling with old school C strings.

Answer (score 0):

> In the example sentence, all the words "pen" are changed to "apple" [Note]: The pen of pineapplepen is not included.

2 issues arise, `"apple"` is longer than `"pen"` so to *change* implies forming a *string* longer than the original.  We need a new space to form the result.

"pen of pineapplepen is not included" implies we need to define the idea of a *word*, perhaps as
`[beginning or whitespace]pen[end or whitespace]`.

---

Consider a 2 pass solution, the first to determine the needed size and 2nd to do the substitution.

Some untested code for OP to see how to implement various issues.

```
// Look for a needle in a haystack
// Replace when found, form result in dest (when not NULL)
// Return string length
size_t sub(char *dest, const char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace) {
  size_t needle_len = strlen(needle);
  size_t replace_len = strlen(replace);
  if (needle_len == 0) {
    TBD_Code();  // Handle pathological case
  }

  bool beginning_of_word = true;
  size_t dest_i = 0;
  
  // Walk the haystack
  for (size_t i = 0; haystack[i]; ) {
    if (beginning_of_word && memcmp(&haystack[i], needle, needle_len) == 0) {
      unsigned char end = haystack[i + needle_len];
      if (isspace(end) || end) {
        if (dest) {
          strcpy(dest + dest_i, replace);
        }
        dest_i += replace_len;
        i += needle_len;
        beginning_of_word = false;
        continue;
      }
    }
    unsigned char ch = haystack[i];
    beginning_of_word = isspace(ch);
    if (dest) {
      dest[dest_i] = ch;
    }
    dest_i++;
    i++;
  }
  if (dest) {
    dest[dest_i] = 0;
  }
  return dest_i;
}
```

Usage

```
const char *example = "I have a pen.I have a pineapple. Uh..pineapplepen. pen pineapple apple pen.";

size_t len = sub(NULL, example, "pen", "apple");
char dest[len + 1];
sub(dest, example, "pen", "apple");
puts(dest);
```

---

The fundamental complexity is that C does not have combined string/memory allocation routines like other languages.  So we need for handle that management with user code.